# MS-SQL query issue: the multi-part identifier not be bound, Invalid object name 'jt0

Tags: sql-server

I dont normally use MS-SQL and I am little confused about whats actually wrong with this query.

```
 SELECT TOP 101 * FROM (
              SELECT  calls.id , calls.recurring_source , calls.status , calls.direction , calls.name  , jt0.name samaw_call_lists_calls_name, jtl0.samaw_call_lists_callssamaw_call_lists_ida samaw_call_lists_callssamaw_call_lists_ida , LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(contacts.first_name,'')+N' '+ISNULL(contacts.last_name,''))) contact_name, jtl1.contact_id contact_id, calls.parent_id , calls.parent_type , calls.date_start , calls.date_entered , calls.assigned_user_id  , ROW_NUMBER()
                                OVER (ORDER BY calls.direction) AS row_number
                                FROM calls  LEFT JOIN calls_cstm ON calls.id = calls_cstm.id_c   LEFT JOIN  samaw_call_lists_calls_c jtl0 ON calls.id=jtl0.samaw_call_lists_callscalls_idb AND jtl0.deleted=0

 LEFT JOIN   jt0 ON jt0.id=jtl0.samaw_call_lists_callssamaw_call_lists_ida AND jt0.deleted=0
 AND jt0.deleted=0  LEFT JOIN  calls_contacts jtl1 ON calls.id=jtl1.call_id AND jtl1.deleted=0

LEFT JOIN  contacts contacts ON contacts.id=jtl1.contact_id AND contacts.deleted=0
AND contacts.deleted=0 where calls.deleted=0 
                            ) AS a
                            WHERE row_number > 0
```

This query was auto generated by script and gives the following error when its run: Invalid object name 'jt0

When I try to run is manually I got this message:

The multi-part identifier "jt0.name" could not be bound.

Is it obvious to anyone what the problem is here?

Comment: Check that table jt0 exists.

Comment: samaw_call_lists exists but calls_name name doesnt. its just name not calls name

Comment: that didn't make any difference. Can you tell which table jt0 is referring to?

Comment: I have created tables and run your query and everything works fine.  I believe that the table JT0 may have a typo or something.  Try Select name from jt0 and see if that works.  Make sure there is no mix up between 0 and O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are missing actual table name for the alias jt0 here,

```
LEFT JOIN   jt0 ON jt0.id=jtl0.samaw_call_lists_callssamaw_call_lists_ida AND jt0.deleted=0
```

there should be actual table name between `LEFT JOIN` and `jt0`.

Comment: yeah this helps a lot!

Comment: A table alias is not needed, this is not causing the error.

Comment: @JoeC - it is the cause of the error if there is no `jt0` table and it was *intended* to be an alias for an (unknown) table that for some reason has ended up blank here.

Comment: if I do LEFT JOIN  samaw_call_lists jt0 ON jt0.id=jtl0.samaw_call_lists_callssamaw_call_lists_ida AND jt0.deleted=0 it now seems to work this alias: samaw_call_lists jt0

Answer (score 2):

A multipart identifier is any description of a field or table that contains multiple parts - for instance `MyTable.SomeRow` - if it can't be bound that means there's something wrong with it - either you've got a simple typo, or a confusion between table and column. It can also be caused by using reserved words in your table or field names and not surrounding them with [].

Something like [redgate sql prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm) is brilliant for avoiding having to manually type these (it even auto-completes joins based on foreign keys), but isn't free. SQL Server Management Studio supports intellisense out of the box, although it isn't quite as complete as the redgate version.

Comment: There's a free version [dbForeg SQL Complete (click)](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) if you don't want to spend money. Helps me a lot.